# NULL = NULL + 1 does not change value from NULL in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I currently have a database with two tables, `products` and `inventory`, and I want to track onhand quantities in the `inventory` table. The `onhand` column is by default NULL when a row is created, and I noticed that if I use a query like below...

`UPDATE inventory SET onhand = onhand + 1 WHERE inventory.prod_id IN (SELECT products.id FROM products WHERE products.upc="012345678911");`

Nothing happens. But if I do this:

`UPDATE inventory SET onhand = 1 WHERE inventory.prod_id IN (SELECT products.id FROM products WHERE products.upc="012345678911");`

Then it works. So I'm guessing it's failing to increment the NULL value to 1. Am I going to have to check if this field is NULL and set to 1, else increment +1, or is there a way to increment from NULL?

Comment: Add a where clause in the end after products.upc appending - ` and onhand <> NULL`

Comment: Common error, for database beginners: **NULL is not 0**. `NULL + NULL = NULL. NULL + 1 = NULL. NULL + anything = NULL`. It's basic SQL. Moreover, you cannot assign anything to NULL, since it's a **value**, not a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` is a special value, the basic rule is that the result of most calculation involving `NULL` is `NULL`. more specifically in SQLite : [Adding anything to null gives null](https://www.sqlite.org/nulls.html)

In your case you can use the [coalesce](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce) function :

```
UPDATE inventory 
SET onhand = coalesce(onhand, 0) + 1 
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Just so I understand coalesce, since the reading is sparse on that one, it's taking onhand and 0 as arguments, and since onhand is NULL, the first non-NULL argument is 0, and so it returns that. Correct?

Comment: Exactly, and if `onhand`  is not `NULL` the value of `coalesce(onhand, 0)` is `onhand`

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks very much!